# Why can't I instantiate a rewarded ad using the following code?

Tags: java, android

All I did is to copy code from [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded)
here it is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AdRequest adRequest;
    RewardedAd mRewardedAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(@NonNull InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {

            }
        });

        adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        RewardedAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917", adRequest,
                new RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError);
                mRewardedAd = null;
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "VIDEO FAILED TO LOAD", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 Log.d("TFO", loadAdError.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull RewardedAd rewardedAd) {
                super.onAdLoaded(rewardedAd);
                mRewardedAd = rewardedAd;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "VIDEO LOADED SUCCESSFULLY", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


       
    }


}
```

I am using test ad IDs and whenever I compile I get the message *VIDEO FAILED TO LOAD* which means that the RewardedAd object has not been instantiated.
I'd appreciate your help if you can provide any.

Comment: u need to look inside of `loadAdError` to see what is the actual error. We cant help u without that information

Comment: The logcart doesn't show any errors

Comment: probably wouldn't show in logcat because you aren't logging it, what is `loadAdError` saying ? you need to check it, use breakpoints, try printing the error it says, anything

Comment: I added the log line to the code and I got this: {
      "Code": 0,
      "Message": "Internal error.",
      "Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
      "Cause": "null",
      "Response Info": {
        "Response ID": "null",
        "Mediation Adapter Class Name": "",
        "Adapter Responses": []
      }
    }